# Thin line where ::after element intersects

Tags: css

I have code that looks like:

```css
.bubble {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 1.3px solid black;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: justify;
  word-break: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
}

.tail {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 12px;
  left: -10px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 10px;
}

.tail::after {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1.3px solid black;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -6px;
  top: -9px;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform: rotate(47deg);
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='bubble'>
  <div class='tail'></div>
  Hi!
</div>
<style>
```

However, on MacOS Chrome there is a thin line in place of the border where there shouldn't be any line at all. Why is that happening and how can I remove it? Thanks!!

[image: Preview]

Comment: try adding `border-right: 0px;` to your `.tail::after`

Comment: im on mac os chrome and not seeing the line

Comment: I'd try to rotate `45deg` instead of `47deg` and make the border width `1px` instead of `1.3px`. And try adjusting the positioning on `.tail::after`, for instance `right:-7px`.